# How to select features when you have image(pixels) with extra information(categories)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pattern-recognition, supervised-learning, multilabel-classification

Suppose you need to train your classifier on a dataset that has images as well as more descriptor features available (along with the labels of-course).

For eg. if you have to classify cats vs dogs, and you are provided with the image, weight and age of each animal. If I just had the image, I could use each pixel as a feature and train my model. I don't want the age and weight to be lost among the pixels **like needles in a haystack(of features)**. Do I make sense ?
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You would be adding them somewhere in the fully connected layer and if the model architecture is adequate and the descriptors are meaningful, I believe your model won't have trouble learning from it. An important issue is to find meaningful descriptors.